# Copy constructor of Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I just read about deep copy of ArrayList, that people think

```
new ArrayList<>(originalList);
```

will create a shallow copy. And I wrote a small demo

```
    ArrayList<String> originalNameList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Anna", "Betty", "Chris"));
    List<String> copyNameList1=originalNameList;
    List<String> copyNameList2= new ArrayList<>(originalNameList);

    originalNameList.add("Duke");
    copyNameList1.add("Ellen");
    copyNameList1.set(1,"Bill");
    copyNameList2.set(0,"Andy");

    System.out.println("originalNameList = " + originalNameList);
    System.out.println("copyNameList1    = " + copyNameList1);
    System.out.println("copyNameList2    = " + copyNameList2);
```

The result:

```
originNameList = [Anna, Bill, Chris, Duke, Ellen]
copyNameList1  = [Anna, Bill, Chris, Duke, Ellen]
copyNameList2  = [Andy, Betty, Chris]
```

I feel that copy constructor of ArrayList is not that shallow. That why people say that so? Are there some levels of deep copy? 
Thank a lot!

Comment: The result is exactly as if shallow copy was executed. What is your expected output, and why?

Comment: You seem to have a different definition of shallow and deep. A shallow copy means that only references to the objects inside the list are copied. That's what happens. A deep copy means that the objects inside the list themselves are copied (i.e. cloned if you prefer), and that the copies would be stored into the new list.

Comment: In Java instances of the String class are supposed to be immutable. How would you observe the difference between a shallow and a deep copy of a collection of immutable objects?

Comment: @PeterT With `==`...

Comment: @PeterT Got it, demo should be go with mutable object, tks

Answer (score 4):

Your definitions for "shallow" and "deep" copy seem to be wrong. It seems like you think a shallow copy means "copying the reference to the object", like this:

```
List<String> copyNameList1=originalNameList;
```

Whereas a "deep" copy creates a new array list:

```
List<String> copyNameList2= new ArrayList<>(originalNameList);
```

Note that the above is a misconception.

A shallow copy **actually** means creating a new array list with the same elements, while a deep copy means creating a new array list that has copies of the elements in the original array list.

The big difference here is "whether the elements in the array list are copied".

Imagine you have an array list object `a1`. It contains references to 3 three objects `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`.

A shallow copy of `a1` will create a new array list object `a2` that contains references to the same `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3` objects.

A deep copy of `a1` will create a new array list object `a2` that contains references to `obj4`, `obj5`, `obj6`, where `obj4`, `obj5` and `obj6` are copies of `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3` respectively.

Here are two methods that shows what happens in shallow copy and deep copy:

```
static ArrayList<String> shallowCopy(ArrayList<String> original) {
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : original) {
        copy.add(s);
    }
    return copy;
}

static ArrayList<String> deepCopy(ArrayList<String> original) {
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : original) {
        String copyOfString = new String(s); // note that each string is copied as well
        copy.add(copyOfString);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

In general, a deep copy copies the objects that the target object refers to as well.

Comment: My mistake is creating a sample with String type, it's immutable type. I just create other with object type and see it clear as you told. Tks a lot!